# At command - Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, at

I'm quite confused by the at command, I am not even sure if something IS happening as I don't get feedback if a task has been added or not.

Is there anywhere I can check added tasks?

Comment: Have you tried typing "at" without any parameters?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the "Task Scheduler" service is started.

type AT from the command line to get a list of scheduled tasks.

If you are running batch files, add a line that will print a date and time into a file.

```
echo start my batch >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
date >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
time >> c:\confirmbatch.txt

all your other commands

echo >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
echo end of my batch >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
date >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
time >> c:\confirmbatch.txt
```

you canput additional echo comments to capture failures along the way. If you're running and other scripting language, you can and should add these types of captures.

Answer (score 3):

If you just enter `at` without any parameters, it will show scheduled tasks.

Also, normally you should get a hint "Added a new job with job ID = x".